# Send and receive one-off faxes within the UK?

Tags: web-apps, fax

I'm looking for software/app where I can send or receive the faxes
within the UK.

I've tried [Fax Burner](http://www.faxburner.com/), [FaxZero](http://faxzero.com/), but they all work in the US (basically the disposable number is US-like) and my sender doesn't want or can't send international faxes.

The question is similar to [a USA question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2010/3474), but this focuses on the UK.

Preferably free of charge (within certain limits) and run on OS X/iOS devices, but I'm open to on-line services as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Faxonline](https://faxonline.co.uk/) which provides an software/app ([Faxapp](https://faxapp.com/) for Windows PCs, Macs, iOS and Android) as well as [on-line access (faxonline)](https://faxonline.co.uk/).

Works within the UK, and you can get your fax number during the registration. There are available free faxpages per each month.

Answer (score 0):

wisefax.com - £1 per fax. Cheaper than letters!